# Why is getResult() only returning an array with only the last record?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm writing a console app in Symfony 3, but for some reason my query results are coming back with only 1 result in the array where I confirmed running it in MySQL and get several results back. Here is the relevant code:

```
$arr_id = array();
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$dql2 = 'SELECT r.productId as pid, COUNT(r.id) as cnt 
          FROM AppBundle:ReferralTrack r 
          WHERE r.productId in (:in) 
          GROUP BY r.productId 
          ORDER BY cnt DESC';
// $arr_id is populated prior to the next command and is, for example, [1,2,3,4,5]
$rt = $em->createQuery($dql2)
    ->setParameters(
        array(
            'in' => implode(',', $arr_id),
        )
    )
;
$traffic_count = $rt->getResult();
```

When I run the query in MySql, the exact same query shown by $rt->getSql() and replace the ? in the query with what is echoed out from implode(',', $arr_id), I get a similar result like this:

```
echo print_r( $traffic_count, 1);
---------------------------------
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [pid] => 11234
        [cnt] => 21
    )

)
```

Here is the query I run in MySQL:

```
SELECT r0_.product_id AS pid, COUNT( r0_.id ) AS cnt
FROM referral_track r0_
WHERE r0_.product_id
IN ( 11234, 57, 58, 60, 61, 9677, 11216, 11217, 11239, 11296 )
GROUP BY r0_.product_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

and it returns 7 results. What I have noticed is that getResult() does seem to always return the LAST record, that is what is shown the the array there. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$rt = $em->createQuery($dql2)
        ->setParameters(
            array(
                'in' => $arr_id,
            )
        )
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks @COil . I understand a good bit of Doctrine nowadays but not sure why it needs an actual array versus the way you'd write it in MySQL.